# Is there a version of NMF that normalizes the sum of scores of each sample?

Tags: normalization, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I want to decompose a nonnegative data matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ into nonnegative basis vectors $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and a score matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$ such that $A \approx UV^T$. If possible, I would also like to constrain the rows of $V$ to each sum to 1, so that they could be interpreted as probability distributions.

I've read about and implemented a few versions of non-negative matrix factorization (NMF) that use multiplicative update rules that are simple to implement, but the proof of their correctness [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf) is a bit past the edge of what I can understand, and I am totally at a loss for how they were derived.

I know it's fairly simple to constrain the *column* sum of $U$ or $V$, which can even be re-normalized after the fact by just applying the inverse transform to the other matrix. But is there any known method to keep the *row* sum of $V$ normalized during optimization, or could this constraint be easily added to an existing algorithm?

Edit: I suppose one strategy would be to do NMF normally, scale the scores uniformly so that they are all $\le 1$, and add an extra basis vector of all zeros with scores equal to $\mathbf{1}^m - V\mathbf{1}^k$ ($\mathbf{1}^m$ being the all-1 column vector of length $m$) to fill in the gaps. I know this does make the columns $U$ not linearly independent, so perhaps questionable, and it is also not necessarily the optimal solution for $k+1$ components, but it might be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: I am still searching for this, did you get a solution?

Comment: Not really - I ended up using the solution I described in the edit, but I still think it's questionable. Ultimately I decided to use a different analysis method for my data that doesn't require making probability distributions out of the rows of V.

Comment: I see, thanks for the update. I don't know if it's legit or not, but currently I am using a simplex projection of the factors to make them normalize. Here is the python code https://gist.github.com/mblondel/6f3b7aaad90606b98f71. I use the matrix version though.